# Planes Question

Tags: calculus, plane-geometry

Give the equations of three planes that meet in three lines. Explain your reasoning? It creates a triangular prism..

Can anyone help me with this? I found the equations but do not know how to explain them.

The three equations are:

$4x + y - 2z = 0 $

$2x - y - 4z = 0 $

$ x + y + z = 6 $

Comment: Hint: what are the intersections?  If x + y + z = 6 and 2x - y - 4x = 0 then 3x - 3z =6 or x - y = 2.  That's a line of intersection between those two planes.   If 2x - y - 4z = 0 and 4x + y - 2z = 0 then 6x - 6z = 0 or x - z = 0.  That's the line of intersection of the other two planes. And finally if 4x + y - 2x = 0 and x + y + z = 6 then 3x - 3z = -6 so x - z = -2. That's the line of intersection of the last pair of planes. So the three lines are x -  z = 2, x - z = 0, x - z = -2.  What do those three lines have in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider taking a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7s63zwLYVE).

You want to show that all 3 planes are NOT parallel by considering the plane's normals. Also consider the intersections: The lines that the planes meet at should have the same slopes i.e. be parallel for a triangular prism.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three planes in the $x-y-z$ coordinates satisfying the desired conditions:

$$x=0, ~y=0, ~y+x=7$$

Comment: The op already has three planes satisfying the conditions.